# Why xamarin update download very slow

Tags: xamarin

The xamarin always has update for my PC and ths osx.This's a good thing I know.
But the VS2015 And the xamarin studio download the update is very slow about 10KB/S.
And if I use VPN to other contry for example US Korea Japan .... Download speed about 50KB/S,slowlly too.

Something useful solution for me?

Comment: I have updated xamarin on Taiwan, it is running smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [downloading the updated Xamarin Studio](https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads) version directly from the Xamarin homepage.

Is it only the update that downloads slowly or is your internet connection slow in general? Have you tried running [speedtest](http://beta.speedtest.net)? What country are you located in?

Comment: China,...... that so terrible for me to wait all one day to download this.